# Why won't this activity in android studio open?

Tags: javascript, java, android, xml, android-studio

I attempted to add an animated submit button to one of my activities when my emulator printed "Can't open app". However, the debugging tool didn't detect an error. I'd greatly appreciate if you could help me resolve this issue.

```
       <com.spark.submitbutton.SubmitButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="428dp"
        android:text="Support"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:sub_btn_background="@color/white"
        app:sub_btn_duration="3000"
        app:sub_btn_line_color="@drawable/catalyzechangebtn"
        app:sub_btn_ripple_color="@drawable/catalyzechangebtn"
        app:sub_btn_tick_color="@color/black" />
```

For additional context, here's the android manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidcodefinder.loginscreendemo">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_background"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".zippage" />
        <activity android:name=".Catalysts.CatalystsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Profile.ProfileActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Analytics.AnalyticsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".postpg"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's a screenshot of the error:
[image]

Comment: does it work on a real device? where is this class `com.spark.submitbutton.SubmitButton`? if it belongs to a library, have you added that dependency?

Comment: share your manifest and app/gradle please

Comment: show how exactly that `Can't open app` looked like

Comment: Post screenshot and check your logs might be an internal error not always have to be with our code.

Comment: Will do. Thank ylu for your help

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this for some tips on how to debug your app.